# Comparator and unknow value with IncomparableValueException

Tags: java, guava

I use this custom comparator

```
List<String> currencies = ImmutableList.of("PLN","EUR","USD","GBP", "CHF");
final Ordering<String> currencyOrdering = Ordering.explicit(currencies);

@Override
public int compare(Account o1, Account o2) {
    return currencyOrdering.compare(o1.getCurrency(),o2.getCurrency());
}
```

But I have error

IncomparableValueException: Cannot compare value: JPY

I would like these unknown values ​​to be randomly at the end...
If possible, how to solve it in standard Java library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do :

```
    List<String> currencies = ImmutableList.of("OTHERS", "PLN","EUR","USD","GBP", "CHF");
    final Ordering<String> currencyOrdering = Ordering.explicit(currencies).onResultOf(lang -> currencies.contains(lang) ? lang : "OTHERS");
    System.out.println(currencyOrdering.compare("JPY", "PLN")); # -1
    System.out.println(currencyOrdering.compare("JPY", "TTT")); # 0
    System.out.println(currencyOrdering.compare("CHF", "GBP")); # 1
```

Basically, I ask Guava to map the languages to their own value if they are in `currencies` list, otherwise I just give them the value `OTHERS` which is the first one in the list (so everything not in the list is put at the start of the list)

Note : you can do it without guava with :

```
    List<String> currencies = List.of("PLN","EUR","USD","GBP", "CHF");
    Comparator<Object> objectComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(currencies::indexOf);
    System.out.println(objectComparator.compare("JPY", "PLN"));
    System.out.println(objectComparator.compare("JPY", "TTT"));
    System.out.println(objectComparator.compare("CHF", "GBP"));
```

Basically, I specify that the "rank" on item is its position in the list. OTHERS is not needed since missing element will have the value `-1`

Comment: thanks for answer, how can I do it in standard Java library? I must do Collections.reverse() to have result without others values in the beginning

Comment: i added an example without guava

Comment: thanks, but I still have another values on the top of list, in the beginning, I must use Collections.reverse to have it in the end... How to ommit this?

Comment: You can add ".reversed()" to a comparator to reverse it.

Comment: What does the code print without the reversed, just as I wrote it ? Me it's : -1, 0, 1. Which means JPY < PLN. JPY=TTT, CHF>GBP. Isn't what you expect ?

Comment: could somehow the remaining currencies be sorted at the end in alphabetical order? How can I fix it?

Comment: something like `Comparator.comparingInt(currencies::indexOf).thenComparing(Object::toString);`